# How to package Dropwizard project without shade plugin?

Tags: java, maven, dropwizard

In every site I can find only examples, where Dropwizard project is built using Shade pluign Is there any way to build Dropwizard project without shade plugin. If so please provide some sample pom.xml.

Comment: I don't have any knowledge about dropwizard, but why do you want to do so ?

Comment: @mtk The fat jar built with shade plugin comes around 20mb and it is difficult to move the artifact to testing environments over slow network speed. So I want dependencies be separated out of the final jar and make it light.

Comment: Have you considered building the artifact on your test environment? See http://gary-rowe.com/agilestack/2013/02/14/how-to-deploy-dynamic-sites-with-git/ for details

Comment: I unpack the jar, then I run `rsync` with `-c` (or `--checksum`) option to update the target environment. I am not sure how to do it with maven (I'm using Gradle), but it should be easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't include the shade plugin in your pom, Dropwizard will build correctly and Maven will give you a jar containing all of your project files but none of your dependencies.